# replace() in R does not work but shows no error message

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

I have a data frame imported from a tsv file with four columns, all digital numbers, with a few "NA" in column 4.

My goal was to create two extra columns in accordance with my current columns, so, column 5 is data as a replica to column 3, except for capping the values to [-5,5]; and then to create column 6 that gives "True" only when value in column 4 <0.05

I did the following, the commands all worked with no error message, however, my data only get capped to that df$C5 is not larger than 5, while it still contains elements smaller than -5, and the NA in df$C6 is not replaced. So, I used replace() for three times, one time it worked, the other two times did not work and showed no error and I am totally confused. Meanwhile, I am also wondering if there is alternative ways to better cap the data aside from replace() ?

Thank you so much!

```
df$C5 <- replace(df$C3,df$C3 >5, 5)

df$C5 <- replace(df$C3,df$C3 <-5, -5)

df$C6 <- df$C4 <0.05

df$C6 <- replace(df$C6,df$C6=="NA","False")
```

Comment: Try `replace(df$C6, is.na(df$C6), FALSE)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see `case_when` function in the `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(C5 = case_when(C3 > 5 ~ 5,
                             C3 < -5 ~ -5,
                             T ~ C3),
              C6 = case_when(C4 < 0.05 ~ TRUE,
                           T~ FALSE))
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you! May I ask what "T ~ C3" is for? I checked on the helper manual on case_when and there is a line "TRUE ~ as.character(x)" which I assume is performing similar function to "T ~ C3" here... is it saying to leave everything else in C5 as what it would be in C3?

Comment: @JoyZheng "T ~ C3" means if C3 is not > 5 or < -5 (2 conditions that are defined above), keep C3's values unchanged. You can read it "else, ~ then do this".